# Second root module in IntelliJ's maven module view

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a multimodule maven application with parent pom as follows:

```
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>uke-management</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>uke-management</name>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>application</module>
    <module>user-management</module>
    <module>security</module>
    <module>workflow</module>
    <module>commons</module>
    <module>database</module>
    <module>contract-management</module>
    <module>file-management</module>
    <module>communication-management</module>
</modules>
```

now in intelliJ's maven module view i can see all modules however `communication-management` is displayed twice and i dont know why. From the structure of my application it seems like it shouldn't be visible as root but somehow is. Here is the `communication-management`'s pom:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <artifactId>uke-management</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>communication-management</artifactId>

<properties>
    <spring-boot-starter-mail>2.1.5.RELEASE</spring-boot-starter-mail>
</properties>

<build>
    // some build plugins
</build>

<dependencies>
    <!-- project dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>user-managment</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot-starter-mail}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and this is how i can see it in IntelliJ:

[image]

Why is `communication-management` displayed twice and why is it displayed as root?

i have already tried reimporting, cleaning etc.

Comment: Can you post the pom.xml for any other module ?

Comment: Is it reproducible with some sample project? Is it possible to share your initioal project (only pom and IDE files, sources might be excluded)?

Comment: just faced it with IDEA 2020.3.3. one module is root (double root!), another one just duplicate (not marked as root).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was some IntelliJ issue, restarting PC solved it. I dont think it's reporoducable. I tried to create some sample project but issue did not occur.

The old "have you tried turning it off and on again" worked for me.

Comment: restarting the Intellij was enough in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I removed .flattened-pom.xml from trouble module. It had another version than others somehow. And then IDEA removed duplicate module annotated as root at runtime.

Comment: You are right. This happens when you have a flat structure in maven